# Foreign key added not saved in django

Tags: django

I have a form where a user can upload files. Upon upload, each file is immediately saved to the db and the id of each file stored in a hidden field on the form. When the form is submitted, the view extracts the ids and attempts to create the relationship between each file and the form object (farm). Although the ids reach the view, the relationships are not saved and I dont understand why - please help.

```
class File(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    event = models.ForeignKey('Event', related_name='files', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    farm = models.ForeignKey('Farm', related_name='files', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

class Farm(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

class FarmCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'directory/farm_registration.html'
    model = Farm

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        farm_form = FarmForm(self.request.POST)

        if farm_form.is_valid():
            new_farm = farm_form.save(commit=False)

            image_upload_ids = self.request.POST.get('_file_ids_photos')
            # confirmed using print that the image ids are added here
            if image_upload_ids:
                image_upload_ids = image_upload_ids.split(',')
                for image in filter(None, image_upload_ids):
                    image_file = File.objects.get(id=image)
                    #confirmed using print that the image_file object is retrieved from the db
                    new_farm.files.add(image_file)

            print('Files count', new_farm.files.count())
            # above line prints 0, even though files are added in the loop above
            new_farm.save()
```

Comment: can you add the code of `FarmForm`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new_farm` hasn't been saved yet, so it doesn't have a primary key. Other items can't be related to it until it does have one - what would they put in their FK field?

You actually don't need the `commit=False` at all. Just save it there at the start of the `is_valid` block; there's no need to save it again at the end, because you haven't changed the Farm object, you've only changed the Files.

(I wonder if the FK relationship is the right one here. That's a one-to-many, so you get existing Files and change whatever Farm they are pointing at to the new one. Is that really what you want to do? I suspect a many-to-many relationship would be better, so files can point to multiple farms.)